# Can memory allocated through mmap overlap the data segment

Tags: c, linux, gcc

The `malloc` function uses both `sbrk` and `mmap` functions. Now the `sbrk` function increases or decreases the data segment. So it grows linearly. Now my question is, is this linearity always maintained, or for example, an `mmap` call can allocate memory overlapping the data segment?

I'm talking about multithreaded programs running on multicore systems. [This blog](http://lifecs.likai.org/2010/02/sbrk-is-not-thread-safe.html) talks about some serious flaws of `sbrk` for multithreaded programs, and it points out that it is possible that memory allocated with `sbrk` can be intermingled with memory alloacted with `mmap` (*The `sbrk` heap could become discontinuous because a `mmaped` region or a shared object obstructs the growth of the heap*).

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say *linearity*, do you mean *contiguity*?

Comment: Yes by linearity I mean contiguity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That blog post doesn't see the forest for the trees; only the `malloc` implementation is allowed to call `sbrk` with a nonzero argument.  More precisely, most `malloc` implementations for Unix will stop functioning correctly (and by that I mean "your program will crash") if application code calls `sbrk` with a nonzero argument.  If you want to make a large allocation directly from the OS you *must* use `mmap` to do it.

(It is true that in a multi-threaded program, `malloc` must internally wrap a mutex around its calls to `sbrk`, but that's an implementation detail.  POSIX says `malloc` is thread safe, that's the important thing for an application programmer.)

`mmap` will not allocate memory *overlapping* the `brk` area unless you use `MAP_FIXED`.  If you use `MAP_FIXED` and your program blows up you get to keep all the pieces.

The kernel tries to avoid doing it, but `mmap` in normal operation could conceivably allocate memory close to the top of the `brk` area.  If this happens, a subsequent `sbrk` call that would collide with the `mmap` region will *fail*.  It will *not* allocate discontiguous memory.  Good implementations of `malloc` ought to detect this condition and start using `mmap` for everything.  I have not actually tried it, but a test program would be pretty easy to write.

Comment: Note also that you cannot know which functions in the implementation call `malloc` (for instance, in glibc even `snprintf` and `dprintf` call `malloc` internally to process the format string), so I would go so far as to say that unless your program uses only async-signal-safe functions, it's extremely unsafe to ever call `sbrk` with a non-zero argument.

Answer (score 3):

> is this linearity always maintained, or for example, an mmap call can allocate memory overlapping the data segment?

Observed behavior is that the brk area is always linear. Implementation details: If enlarging the brk area is not possible, for example due to a blocking mapping, glibc will switch to mmap-only. Small allocations (<128KB) seem to be obtained by glibc via brk if possible, so blocking that with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(void)
{
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 1024; ++i) {
                malloc(2048);
                if (i == 512) {
                        void *r, *end = sbrk(0);
                        r = mmap(end, 4096, PROT_NONE,
                           MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);
                }
        }
}
```

when straced, yields indeed

```
[...]
brk(0x1e7d000)                          = 0x1e7d000
mmap(0x1e7d000, 4096, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0) = 0x1e7d000
brk(0x1e9e000)                          = 0x1e7d000   <-- (!)
mmap(NULL, 1048576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbfd9bc9000
```